# Integrate using SciPy with variable integrand members and put into meshgrid

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I'm looking to plot a vector field where the two components are determined from a numerical integration, and the integration is calculated using the coordinates in space where the vector is to be drawn.

In the code below I define the integrand functions to be dependent on `r` and `z`, then in a loop define their values and evaluate both integrals at each (r,z).

I have two questions:

1) Is there a more pythonic way to evaluate these integrals with the variable `r` and `z`?

2) What is the best way to store the values of the integrals along with their coordinates to generate a `quiver` plot from `meshgrid`s?

```
import scipy.integrate as spi
import scipy.special as sps
import numpy as np

R = 2
V = 10

def Efield_r_integrand(k):
    return np.exp(-k*z)*k*R*V*sps.jv(1,k*r)*sps.jv(1,k*R)

def Efield_z_integrand(k):
    return np.exp(-k*z)*k*R*V*sps.jv(0,k*r)*sps.jv(1,k*R)

x_max = 3.0
z_max = 3.0
n_pts = 20

for i in xrange(n_pts):
    r = float(i)/float(n_pts)*r_max
    for j in xrange(n_pts):
        z = float(j)/float(n_pts)*z_max
        current_Efield_r = spi.quad(Efield_r_integrand,0,np.inf)[]
        current_Efield_z = spi.quad(Efield_z_integrand,0,np.inf)[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fairly pythonic already, with the exception of the construct

```py
for i in xrange(n_pts):
    r = float(i)/float(n_pts)*r_max
```

which is reminescent of some other programming languages. In Python, it would be more pythonic to write

```
for r in np.arange(0, rmax, rmax/n_pts):
```

as you don't need the intermediate variable `i`.

That being said, evaluating an integral of a function that is defined on a grid is something for which I wouldn't write the double for-loop anymore, but let the convenience function [`np.vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) take care of:

```py
import scipy.integrate as spi
import scipy.special as sps
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Efield_r_integrand(k, z, r, R, V):
    return np.exp(-k*z)*k*R*V*sps.jv(1,k*r)*sps.jv(1,k*R)

def Efield_z_integrand(k, z, r, R, V):
    return np.exp(-k*z)*k*R*V*sps.jv(0,k*r)*sps.jv(1,k*R)

x_max, z_max, n_pts = 3.0, 3.0, 20
R, V = 2, 10

Z, X = np.mgrid[0:z_max:n_pts*1j, 0:x_max:n_pts*1j] # note that this creates a grid with the boundaries (0 and 3.0) included! 

def integrate_on_grid(func, lo, hi, *args):
    """Returns a callable that can be evaluated on a grid."""
    return np.vectorize(lambda n,m: spi.quad(func, lo, hi, (n,m)+args)[0])

Efield_r, Efield_z = [integrate_on_grid(func, 0, np.inf, R, V)(Z,X)
    for func in (Efield_r_integrand, Efield_z_integrand)]

plt.quiver(X, Z, Efield_r, Efield_z)
```

The last line shows how you can easily use the results obtained thus far to generate a `quiver` plot.
There is still some repetition that could be removed: `Efield_r_integrand` is up to one factor the same as `Efield_z_integrand`, which ideally would be solved by having `quad` understand that if the return value of a call to the integrand is an array, it means integration over each element of the array. However, that's not the way it works, but I digress. You could create one more function that takes the common factors in those equations and call that, but that's up to personal tastes.